# How can I optimise my Haskell so I don't run out of memory

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, traveling-salesman, strictness

For an online algorithms course I am attempting to write a program which calculates the travelling salesman distance of cities using an approxomation algorithm:

1. Start the tour at the first city.
2. Repeatedly visit the closest city that the tour hasn't visited yet.  In case of a tie, go to the closest city with the lowest
   index.  For example, if both the third and fifth cities have the
   same distance from the first city (and are closer than any other
   city), then the tour should begin by going from the first city to
   the third city.
3. Once every city has been visited exactly once, return to the first city to complete the tour.

I am trying to write a solution in Haskell, and I have it working on small data sets, but it runs out of memory on a large input (the course has an input of ~33000 cities)

```
-- Fold data: cities map, distances map, visited map, list of visited cities and each distance,
-- and current city
data TS = TS (M.Map Int City) (M.Map (Int,Int) Double) (M.Map Int Bool) ([(Int,Double)]) (Int)

run :: String -> String
run input = let cm = parseInput input -- cityMap contains cities (index,xPos,yPos)
                n = length $ M.keys cm
                dm = buildDistMap cm -- distanceMap :: M.Map (Int,Int) Double
                                     -- which is the distance between cities a and b
                ts = TS cm dm (M.fromList [(1,True)]) [(1,0.0)] 1
                (TS _ _ _ beforeLast _) = foldl' (\ts _ -> exec ts n) ts [2..n]
                completed = end beforeLast dm
             in show $ floor $ sum $ map (\(_,d) -> d) $ completed

exec :: TS -> Int -> TS
exec (TS cm dm visited ordered curr) n =
  let candidateIndexes = [(i)|i<-[1..n],M.member i visited == False]
      candidates = map (\i -> let (Just x) = M.lookup (curr,i) dm in (x,i)) candidateIndexes
      (dist,best) = head $ sortBy bestCity candidates
      visited' = M.insert best True visited
      ordered' = (best,dist) : ordered
   in  TS cm dm visited' ordered' best

end :: [(Int,Double)] -> M.Map (Int,Int) Double -> [(Int,Double)]
end ordering dm = let (latest,_) = head ordering
                      (Just dist) = M.lookup (latest,1) dm
                   in (1,dist) : ordering

bestCity :: (Double,Int) -> (Double,Int) -> Ordering
bestCity (d1,i1) (d2,i2) =
  if compare d1 d2 == EQ
     then compare i1 i2
     else compare d1 d2
```

At first I wrote the function `exec` as a recursive function instead of calling it via the `foldl'`. I thought changing it to use `foldl'` would solve my issue as `foldl'` is strict. However it appears to have made no difference in memory usage. I have tried compiling my program using no optimisations and `-O2` optimisations.

I know that somehow it must be keeping multiple loops in memory as I can sort 34000 numbers without issue using

```
> sort $ [34000,33999..1]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Just in case it is any use here is the `parseInput` and `buildDistMap` functions, but they are not the source of my issue

```
data City = City Int Double Double deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Init
parseInput :: String -> M.Map Int City
parseInput input =
  M.fromList
  $ zip [1..]
  $ map ((\(i:x:y:_) -> City (read i) (read x) (read y)) . words)
  $ tail
  $ lines input

buildDistMap :: M.Map Int City -> M.Map (Int,Int) Double
buildDistMap cm =
  let n = length $ M.keys cm
      bm = M.fromList $ zip [(i,i)|i<-[1..n]] (repeat 0) :: M.Map (Int,Int) Double
      perms = [(x,y)|x<-[1..n],y<-[1..n],x/=y]
   in foldl' (\dm (x,y) -> M.insert (x,y) (getDist cm dm (x,y)) dm) bm perms

getDist :: M.Map Int City -> M.Map (Int,Int) Double -> (Int,Int) -> Double
getDist cm dm (x,y) =
  case M.lookup (y,x) dm
        of (Just v) -> v
           Nothing -> let (Just (City _ x1 y1)) = M.lookup x cm
                          (Just (City _ x2 y2)) = M.lookup y cm
                       in eDist (x1,y1) (x2,y2)

eDist :: (Double,Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double
eDist (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt $ p2 (x2 - x1) + p2 (y2 - y1)
  where p2 x = x ^ 2
```

And some test input

```
tc1 = "6\n\
  \1 2 1\n\
  \2 4 0\n\
  \3 2 0\n\
  \4 0 0\n\
  \5 4 3\n\
  \6 0 3"
```

Comment: Can you compute distances on the fly instead of all up-front? 33k*33k ~= 1 billion seems like a nontrivial number of distances to store.

Comment: Aside, a positional `data` type with many fields and a comment explaining each one isn’t any better than a large tuple; this probably wants to be a record with named fields. More to the point, most of them should probably be strict, too, or else the use of `foldl'` doesn’t force any of them, just the `TS` constructor. Something like: `data TS = TS { tsCities :: !(M.Map Int City), …, tsCurrent :: !Int }`. `NamedFieldPuns` is also handy for this kind of code (and not as implicit/magical as `RecordWildCards`).

Comment: @JonPurdy yes that is a good point about it not being better than a tuple. Admittedly I was hacking a few things together to try and get it to work, and not going about this in the best way. I didn't realise you could declare a record type as strict though so that is a great tip, thanks. I presume that means I don't need to use `seq` then to force the strictness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data TS = TS (M.Map Int City) (M.Map (Int,Int) Double) (M.Map Int Bool) ([(Int,Double)]) (Int)



(TS _ _ _ beforeLast _) = foldl' (\ts _ -> exec ts n) ts [2..n]



exec :: TS -> Int -> TS
exec (TS cm dm visited ordered curr) n =
  let ...
  in  TS cm dm visited' ordered' best
```

That `foldl'` is doing a lot less than you hope. It causes the `TS` constructor to be evaluated at every step, but nothing in that evaluation process requires `visited'`, `ordered'`, or `best` to be evaluated.  (`cm` and `dm` aren't modified in the loop, so they can't stack up unevaluated thunks.)

The best way to solve this is to make the evaluation of the `TS` constructor returned by `exec` depend on evaluating `visited'`, `ordered'`, and `best` sufficiently.

`M.Map` is always spine-strict, so evaluating a map at all means the whole structure is evaluated. Whether the values are as well depends on how you imported it, but that turns out to not be relevant here. The value you're inserting is a nullary constructor, so it's already fully evaluated. So evaluating `visited'` to WHNF is sufficient.

`Int` is not a nested type, so evaluating `best` to WHNF is sufficient.

`[(Int, Double)]` (the outer parens are redundant, the list brackets do grouping of their contents) is a bit trickier. Lists aren't spine strict, nor are pairs strict. But looking at the construction pattern, this is a prepend-only structure. As such, you don't need to worry about the tail. If the list was evaluated coming in, the output will be evaluated as long as the new head is. Unfortunately, that means you've got to be a bit careful with the pair. Half of it is the same `best` value as constructed above, so that's not too bad. If it's evaluated, it's evaluated! (Though this does suggest you don't need to be passing it at every iteration, you could just use the front of `ordered`.) The other half of the pair is a `Double`, which is also non-nested, so WHNF is sufficient for it.

In this particular case, due to the fact that different approaches are necessary, I'd probably just approach this with `seq`.

```
let ... all the same stuff ...
in  visited' `seq` dist `seq` best `seq` TS ... all the same stuff ...
```

Note that I'm being careful to force the minimal number of values to remove unnecessary nesting of thunks. The `(,)` and `(:)` constructors don't need to be evaluated, only their arguments - the place where nested thunks might build up. (What's the difference in memory consumption between `<thunk <expression> <expression>>` and `<constructor <expression> <expression>>`?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think that I understand the theorey of what you are saying. However, it looks to me like the only code change you have suggested is change the final line in the `exec` function to "   in visited' `seq` dist `seq` best `seq` TS cm dm visited' ordered' best`" but I have tried that and I am still running into the same issue. Have I misunderstood your instructions? If so I apologise

Comment: @mattematt Oh, I ignored `buildDistMap` and maybe I shouldn't have. What's your import of `M`?

Comment: I think that is my fault as I may be wrong about saying which section has the issue. My import is 'import qualified Data.Map as M'. Maybe Daniel is correct that me caching the entire set of values is the issue also

Comment: Yeah, I think the cache was the immediate problem. But you would have run into problems without changes to `exec` as well. It was not going to play nicely with `foldl'`.

Comment: yes I agree. I am going to mark your answer as answering my question as I still think that is clear what would optimise my code. Thanks for the answer and the other tips

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Carl for his extremely detailed answer. Also to Daniel for pointing out that caching the huge amounts of distances could actually be causing my memory issues. I was assuming because my code had got past that function that I had enough memory for that - forgetting Haskell is lazy and was only building that map in the `exec` function as I was actually using it.

I solved this problem now in a cleaner way. I am using a `Data.Set` of all the city indexes I still need to visit, and then because the cities were given in order of `X` values I know that the nearest cities on the plane will also be the nearest cities by index. Knowing this I set a value to take a slice from the set either side of the index at each iteration and use this slice to check for distances to my current city, and this allows me to calculate the distance to the next city at each iteration without caching that huge amount of data.

```
-- How many cities in each direction (index) to consider
-- smaller is faster but less accurate
searchWidth = 1000 :: Int

data TS = TS (M.Map Int City) (S.Set Int) [(Double,Int)] Int

run :: String -> String
run input =
  let cm = parseInput input
      n = length $ M.keys cm
      toVisit = S.fromList [1..n]
      ts = TS cm toVisit [(0.0,1)] 1
      (TS _ _ beforeLast _) = foldl' (\ts i -> trace (concat [show i,"/",show n]) exec ts) ts [2..n]
      afterLast = end cm beforeLast
   in show $ floor $ sum $ map (\(d,_) -> d) afterLast

exec :: TS -> TS
exec (TS cm toVisit visited curr) =
  let (Just (City _ cx cy)) = M.lookup curr cm
      index = S.findIndex curr toVisit
      toVisit' = S.deleteAt index toVisit
      lb = let x = index - searchWidth in if x < 0 then 0 else x
      ub = let x = index + searchWidth - lb in if x >= length toVisit' then (length toVisit') else x
      candidateIndexes = S.take ub $ S.drop lb toVisit'
      candidates = S.map (\i -> let (Just (City _ x y)) = M.lookup i cm in (eDist (x,y) (cx,cy),i)) candidateIndexes
      (dist,next) = S.findMin candidates
      visited' = (dist,next) : visited
   in toVisit' `seq` dist `seq` next `seq` TS cm toVisit' visited' next

end :: M.Map Int City -> [(Double,Int)] -> [(Double,Int)]
end cm visited =
  let (_,currI) = head visited
      (Just (City _ cx cy)) = M.lookup currI cm
      (Just (City _ lx ly)) = M.lookup 1 cm
      dist = eDist (cx,cy) (lx,ly)
   in (dist,1) : visited
```

Using a `Data.Set` also comes with the added bonus that it automatically sorts the values inside, making getting the next travel location trivial.

I realise this isn't the best Haskell code in the world and that I am doing some naughty things like matching `Just` straight out of map lookups rather than working with the `Maybe` values. Additionally it has been pointed out to me that I should be using a record rather than a `data` type to construct my `TS`